# Binary Search Tree to String

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, stringbuilder

I need to make a method that converts a BST to a string, each child prefixed with an indent character.

example:

```
BinaryTreeSet set=new BinaryTreeSet();
set.add(6);
set.add(4);
set.add(3);
set.add(5);
set.add(9);
set.add(10);
set.add(8);
set.add(0);
System.out.println(set.treeString());
```

should produce

```
=> 6
  => 4
    => 3
      => 0
    => 5
  => 9
    => 8
    => 10
```

I have tried for a few hours now, but i don't make any progress.

The best i could get was

```
=> 6
=> 0
=> 3
=> 5
=> 4
=> 8
=> 10
=> 9
```

with following code:

```
public String treeString() {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("=> " + root);
    builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    nodeString(root, builder);

    return builder.toString();

    }

    private void nodeString(BinaryTreeNode node, StringBuilder builder) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (node.left != null) {
            nodeString(node.left, builder);
            builder.append("=> " + node.left);
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            nodeString(node.right, builder);
            builder.append("=> " + node.right);
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }
```

Somehow i cant figure out how to get the order right...
Also i have no real idea on how to make the indent properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Your example (when adding the values) doesn't correspond the desired output if you're using BST. `set.add(6); set.add(4); set.add(3);` should produce 6 as root, 4 as left leaf and 3 as right leaf ...

Comment: Then we have learned a different definition of BST!

Ours is that the left child needs to be smaller than its parent, right needs to be bigger.

Thanks anyway, i got it working!

Comment: @shoeni Well ...you're correct. I got another tree in mind. using `set.add(6); set.add(4); set.add(3);` in a BST should indeed deliver a 6 a root, 4 as left and 3 as left of 4. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing the `builder.append` lines *before* the recursive `nodeString` calls. If you additionally need indentation as in your example output you will also need to keep track of the call depth in your recursive calls.

Comment: thanks, solved the order problem perfectly. I'll post my finished code once i get the indentation done!

Answer (score 0):

This works to solve the problem for the definition of BST we learned:

```
private void nodeString(BinaryTreeNode node, StringBuilder builder, int count) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Left
        if (node.left != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { // Adding indent
                builder.append("  ");
            }
            builder.append("=> " + node.left);
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            nodeString(node.left, builder, ++count);
            --count;
        }
        // Right
        if (node.right != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { // Adding indent
                builder.append("  ");
            }
            builder.append("=> " + node.right);
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            nodeString(node.right, builder, ++count);
            --count;
        }
    }
```